# jquery-3.1.1.js:3855 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).loadingModal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on MVC 5 asp.net, i have a view registration which uses layout, What i want is when user click on add button a loader loads and destroy after ajax response, i can achieve this by not using layout, but when i use layout it gives this error
[Uncaught TypeError: $(...).loadingModal is not a function
    at showModal (registration.js:7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3y0y.png)

my script sequence is
       `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>`
        `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.loadingModal.js"></script>`
       `<script src="~/Scripts/registration.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me my problem was i had two `scripts` of  `jquery` one on the current page and one on the `layout` page.

> Make sure you have only single version of `scripts`.

Comment: thank you so much @Mudasir, as i was using template , there is a js file vendor.js which also has jquery in it but i was referencing itafter render(); and before render(); i was  referencing  jquery.js , means there is **two scripts of  jquery** , finally i found solution.

Comment: Glad to here. Best of luck.